# How do I perform a count on a relation with a where clause in prisma?

Tags: prisma

I have the following query which gives all posts and a count of all comments. Now I'd like to get a count of all comments with the post that have the approved field set to true. I can't seem to figure this out.

```
prisma.post.findMany({
    include: {
      _count: { select: { Comment: true } },
    },
  });
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can put the condition in the where clause.
I think you still want to return all records though and want just the count of it.
In that case you can go ahead with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use [Raw Query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) to achieve this as the filter on `_count` for relations is not supported yet.

Here's the Feature Request for the same: [Ability to filter count in "Count Relation Feature"](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8413)

[Edit: 14-Nov-2022]

Prisma has added support for filteredRelationCount since version [4.3.0](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/aggregation-grouping-summarizing#filter-the-relation-count)

Answer (score 11):

Available since [4.3.0](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/aggregation-grouping-summarizing#filter-the-relation-count).

enable in your schema file:

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["filteredRelationCount"] << add this 
}
```

and then query:

```
await prisma.post.findMany({
  select: {
    _count: {
      select: {
        comment: { where: { approved: true } },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: What if I want to get only those whose quantity is a certain number? Following the case, the post with 4 comments, for example.